# How to generate scaffold files using Rail's generate on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am creating a site that will sell phones and I have tables and products all set up.

When I run:

```
rails generate Scaffold Sale item_id:integer employee_id:integer
```

I get a Ruby file called 'Sale' and 'Part.rb' in my app/models. I am not getting the two Ruby files I need, which are 'Emlployee.rb' and 'Item.rb'.

I need these  files in order to keep track of which employee sold which phone. When I navigate to my site /sales there is a table but when I navigate to /employees to add a new employee Cloud0 tells me path is unspecified.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, `rails generate scaffold sale` only generates the model etc. for sale. Specifying `item_id:integer` includes the `item_id` field on the `sales` table so you can use an association, but the `Item` and `Employee` models must be created separately.

Comment: If you refer to a previous question you need to provide a link. But your question should be stand-alone because SO questions are not threads, they are articles. Your expertise or experience isn't important to us, and mentioning it is merely distracting. Read "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" to learn what we need.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate scaffold Sale item_id:integer employee_id:integer
```

Only creates the stuff that belongs to the `Sale`. So, in your case with this command you created a `Sale.rb` model that has two attributes - `item_id` and `employee_id` (`scaffold` creates also it's assets, controller, routes and tests).

If you need to create also `Employee` and `Item` models, you'll need to create them separately.

```
> rails g model Employee
> rails g model Item
```

Read also the [difference between scaffold and model in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734378/difference-between-scaffold-and-model-in-rails) and the [documentation about the generate command](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).